# How to transform string of space-separated key,value pairs of unique words into a dict

Tags: python, list, loops, split, iteration

I've got a string with words that are separated by spaces (all words are unique, no duplicates). I turn this string into list:

```
s = "#one cat #two dogs #three birds"
out = s.split()
```

And count how many values are created:

```
print len(out) # Says 192
```

Then I try to delete everything from the list:

```
for x in out:
     out.remove(x)
```

And then count again:

```
print len(out) # Says 96
```

Can someone explain please why it says 96 instead of 0?

MORE INFO

Each line starts with '#' and is in fact a space-separated pair of words: the first in the pair is the key and second is the value.

So, what I am doing is:

```
for x in out:
     if '#' in x: 
          ind = out.index(x) # Get current index 
          nextValue = out[ind+1] # Get next value 
          myDictionary[x] = nextValue
          out.remove(nextValue)
          out.remove(x)
```

The problem is I cannot move all key,value-pairs into a dictionary since I only iterate through 96 items.

Comment: "Then I try to delete everything from the list" -- let's dig deeper here.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I am moving values from the list to a dictionary in pairs, like the first value in pair is the key and second goes as the value. The thing is my dictionary is incomplete due to I cannot iterate through the list in full - it says there is only 96 indexes.

Comment: If you can post the code with the string and dict you are using, it will be easier for us to offer a solution. The problem may be somewhere other than what you have given us so far.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Comment: You should not delete items from list which you are iterating .. this is undefined behavior.. better use list comprehension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you actually want something like this:

```
s = '#one cat #two dogs #three birds'
out = s.split()
entries = dict([(x, y) for x, y in zip(out[::2], out[1::2])])
```

What is this code doing?  Let's break it down.  First, we split `s` by whitespace into `out` as you had.

Next we iterate over the pairs in `out`, calling them "`x, y`".  Those pairs become a `list` of tuple/pairs.  `dict()` accepts a list of size two tuples and treats them as `key, val`.

Here's what I get when I tried it:

```
$ cat tryme.py

s = '#one cat #two dogs #three birds'
out = s.split()
entries = dict([(x, y) for x, y in zip(out[::2], out[1::2])])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(entries)

$ python tryme.py
{'#one': 'cat', '#three': 'birds', '#two': 'dogs'}
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Thank you a lot. Is there a way I could also include a condition into this process? Because I need to modify some of the values before passing them into a dictionary. I need to get rid off a hash sign, did that through entries = dict([(x[1:], y) for x, y in zip(out[::2], out[1::2])]) but in some cases I would need to modify certain characters, for example, if the word contains 'keyword' I need to replace it with another word.

Comment: Rewrite the "list comprehension" as a traditional `for`-loop.  First line is like "`for key, val in zip(out[::2], out[1::2]):` and then you can do whatever you want to `key` or `val`.  Then add them to your dict like so: `entries[key] = val`.  Don't forget to create the dict at the beginning, `entries = {}`, e.g.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 13):

As for what actually happened in the **for** loop:

> **From the** [**Python for statement documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):
>
> The expression list is evaluated *once*; it should yield an iterable
>   object. An iterator is created for the result of the `expression_list`.
>   The suite is then executed *once* for each item provided by the
>   iterator, **in the order of ascending indices**. Each item in turn is
>   assigned to the target *list* using the standard rules for assignments,
>   and then the suite is executed. **When the items are exhausted** (which is
>   immediately when the sequence is **empty**), the suite in the `else` clause,
>   if present, is executed, and the `loop` **terminates**.

I think it is best shown with the aid of an **illustration**.

Now, suppose you have an `iterable object` (such as `list`) like this:

```
out = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

What happen when you do `for x in out` is that it **creates internal indexer** which goes like this (I illustrate it with the symbol `^`):

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
 ^  <-- here is the indexer
```

What normally happen is that: as you finish one cycle of your loop, **the indexer moves forward** like this:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 2
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 3
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 4
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 5
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 6
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

#finish, no element is found anymore!
```

> As you can see, the indexer **keeps moving forward till the end of your
>   list, regardless of what happened to the list**!

Thus when you do `remove`, this is what happened internally:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1 - a is removed!
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 2
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, e, f] #cycle 2 - c is removed
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, e, f] #cycle 3
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, f] #cycle 3 - e is removed
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

#the for loop ends
```

Notice that there are only **3 cycles** there instead of **6 cycles**(!!) (which is the number of the elements in the original list). And that's why you left with **half** `len` of your original `len`, because that is the number of cycles it takes to complete the loop when you remove one element from it for each cycle.

---

If you want to clear the list, simply do:

```
if (out != []):
    out.clear()
```

Or, alternatively, to remove the element one by one, you need to do it **the other way around - from the end to the beginning**. Use `reversed`:

```
for x in reversed(out):
    out.remove(x)
```

---

Now, why would the `reversed` work? If the indexer keeps moving forward, wouldn't `reversed` also should not work because the number of element is reduced by one per cycle anyway?

No, it is not like that,

> Because `reversed` method **changes** the way to the internal indexer
>   works! What happened when you use `reversed` method is **to make the
>   internal indexer moves backward** (from the end) instead of
>   **forward**.

To illustrate, this is what normally happens:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 2
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 3
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 4
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 5
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 6
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

#finish, no element is found anymore!
```

And thus when you do one removal per cycle, it doesn't affect how the indexer works:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e] #cycle 1 - f is removed
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e] #cycle 2
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d] #cycle 2 - e is removed
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d] #cycle 3
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c] #cycle 3 - d is removed
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c] #cycle 4
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b] #cycle 4 - c is removed
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b] #cycle 5
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a] #cycle 5 - b is removed
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a] #cycle 6
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[] #cycle 6 - a is removed
 ^  <-- here is the indexer
```

Hope the illustration helps you to understand what's going on internally...

Comment: This is one of the best explanations of modifying during iteration that I've ever seen. I wish I could upvote this more than once!

Comment: You gave an explicit explanation to my answer! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Was just about to post a tiny example, thanks for addressing the actual question!

Answer (score 3):

You're not being specific. Why are you trying to delete everything in the out-list? Any if all you need to do is clear the out-list, why not just do this:

```
out = []
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're encountering is the result of modifying a list while iterating over it.  When an item is removed, everything after it gets moved forward by one index, but the iterator does not account for the change and continues by incrementing the index it last accessed.  The iterator thus skips every second element in the list, which is why you're left with half the number of elements.

The simplest direct solution to your problem is to iterate over a *copy* of `out`, using slice notation:

```
for x in out[:]:
    # ...
    out.remove(x)
```

However, there is a deeper question here:  why do you need to remove items from the list at all?  With your algorithm, you are guaranteed to end up with an empty list, which is of no use to you.  It would be both simpler and more efficient to just iterate over the list without removing items.

When you're done with the list (after the for-loop block) you can explicitly delete it (using the `del` keyword) or simply leave it for Python's garbage collection system to deal with.

A further issue remains: you're combining direct iteration over a list with index-based references.  The use of `for x in out` should typically be restricted to situations where you want to access each element independently of the others.  If you want to work with indices, use `for i in range(len(out))` and access elements with `out[i]`.

Furthermore, you can use a *dictionary comprehension* to accomplish your entire task in a one-line pythonic expression:

```
my_dictionary = {out[i]: out[i + 1] for i in range(len(out)) if "#" in out[i]}
```

Another pythonic alternative would be to make use of the fact that each even-numbered element is a key, and each odd-numbered element is a value (you'd have to assume that the list result of `str.split()` consistently follows this pattern), and use `zip` on the even and odd sub-lists.

```
my_dictionary = dict(zip(out[::2], out[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want following.

```
>>> a = '#one cat #two dogs #three birds'
>>> b = { x.strip().split(' ')[0] : x.strip().split(' ')[-1] for x in a.strip().split('#') if len(x) > 0 }
>>> b
{'three': 'birds', 'two': 'dogs', 'one': 'cat'}
```

Or even better

```
>>> b = [ y   for x in a.strip().split('#') for y in x.strip().split(' ') if len(x) > 0 ]
>>> c = { x: y for x,y  in zip(b[0::2],b[1::2]) }
>>> c
{'three': 'birds', 'two': 'dogs', 'one': 'cat'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to clear the list,

use
`out = []`
or
`out.clear()`

Anyway, that you said is because `remove` function of list affects list.

```
out = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
for x in out:
    out.remove(x)
    print(x)
```

then result is shown below:

a
c
e

It is exactly half of full list. So, in your case, you got 96(half of 192) from 192.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is whenever you delete a value from the list, that particular list restores its values dynamically.
That is, when you perform `out.remove(ind)` and `out.remove(ind+1)`, the values in these indexes are deleted,
but they are replaced with new values which are predecessor of the previous value.

Therefore to avoid this you have to implement the code as follows :

```
out = []
out = '#one cat #two dogs #three birds'.split()

print "The list is : {0} \n".format(out)
myDictionary = dict()

for x in out:

    if '#' in x:
        ind = out.index(x)  # Get current index
        nextValue = out[ind+1]  # Get next value
        myDictionary[x] = nextValue

out = []  # #emptying the list
print("The dictionary is : {0} \n".format(myDictionary))
```

So, after you are done transferring the values from the list to dictionary, we could safely empty the `out` by
using `out = []`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using remove(x) while iterating. 'out' variable is referring both in remove function and for-loop.

Just use

```
for i in range(len(out)):
     out.remove(out[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you split on '#' to get each record (a string of key,value pair). Then you split each o on space, to give you a list of [key,value]. `dict()` allows you to construct the dict directly from a list of key,value-pairs. So:

```
>>> dict( k_v.split() for k_v in s.split('#')[1:] )
{'one': 'cat', 'two': 'dogs', 'three': 'birds'}
```

(Note: we had to use `s.split('#')[1:]` to skip the first (blank) record)