# For-loop statement evaluation

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

It's agreed upon that the iterable item in a `for` loop is evaluated only once. Hence, the output `f called` is printed once.

What I'm struggling to figure out is, why am I not getting an `out-of-bound error`? Since at the time of the evaluation, the length was equal to `100`.

```
mylist = [x for x in range(100)]

def printmylist(thelist):
    print("f called")
    return thelist

for i, item in enumerate(printmylist(mylist)):
    print(len(mylist))
    del mylist[len(mylist) - i - 1]

f called 100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51
```

Comment: If enumerate() in the initial evaluation provided 100 items, why are the instructions not called 100 times, if the expression is only evaluated once? Not sure if what I'm asking makes sense or not.

Answer (score 2):

In the `for` loop, you use the current length of the list to evaluate the location to delete. And, you delete from the end of the list. So your loop only iterates 50 times.

If you change the `print` statement to display `i`, you will find it only counts from 0 to 49.

Answer (score 2):

Though the `print("f called")` is only called once, the variable (called `iterable object` which stores the evaluation value of `enumerate(printmylist(mylist))` in your case has its referred `set` change from time to time because you remove the enumeration one by one. At first you have all the 100 items, but it is reduced one by one:

```
Note: len(mylist) - i - 1 = 99, delete index 99 -> 100 removed
1 2 3 ... 98 99 100 #len(mylist) = 100 
^ <-- here is i = 0

Note: len(mylist) - i - 1 = 98, delete index 98 -> 99 removed
1 2 3 ... 98 99 #len(mylist) = 99
  ^ <-- here is i = 1

Note: len(mylist) - i - 1 = 97, delete index 97 -> 98 removed
1 2 3 ... 98 #len(mylist) = 98
    ^ <-- here is i = 2

... and so on
```

Plus, since `i` will be checked every end of the loop against that variable (the `iterable object`, therefore, you only print `50` items out of `100` items.

> **From the** [**Python for statement documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):
>
> The expression list is evaluated *once*; it should yield an iterable
>   object. An iterator is created for the result of the `expression_list`.
>   The suite is then executed *once* for each item provided by the
>   iterator, **in the order of ascending indices**. Each item in turn is
>   assigned to the target *list* using the standard rules for assignments,
>   and then the suite is executed. **When the items are exhausted** (which is
>   immediately when the sequence is **empty**), the suite in the `else` clause,
>   if present, is executed, and the `loop` **terminates**.

To simplify, imagine you have

```
v = enumerate(printmylist(mylist)) #v is the iterable object
```

Though it is only evaluated once, the `set` where `v` is pointed to changes every time you remove an item but `i` iterates over `v`. Thus, `i` is going to be increasing increasing till finally `i = 50`.

```
.
.
.

v = ... 50, i = 49
        ^ <-- here is i and is in v

v = ... 50    , i = 50 and is out from v
           ^ <-- no more item found
```

No more item is left to be evaluated beyond the border. Thus you get the results:

```
100 99 ... 51
```

And not getting out of bounds.

[More on how for works internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618307/how-to-transform-string-into-dict/35618686#35618686), including how it creates internal indexer and checks it against the value pointed by the termination value every time.

Comment: In other words, am I right to say that the _expression_ is only evaluated once, but the iterable item referred to is reevaluated after each iteration? Thanks for the link, and your answer.