# Using ternary operator in python?

Tags: python, ternary-operator

Consider the following code snippet. It flags a syntax error at the break statement.

```
digits = list(str(102))
dummy = list(str(102/2))
for j in digits:
    dummy.remove(j) if j in dummy else break
```

How do I fix this?(I want to still use the ternary operator)

Comment: `break` is a statement, and as such it *can't* be used inside a ternary. Sorry.

Comment: I don't think you can use ternary operator for that case...

Comment: To remove an element from a list you probably need to be careful (safer is to do the reverse way). check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618307/how-to-transform-string-into-dict/35618686#35618686 see also Padraic's answer

Comment: @MarkRansom That's wrong reasoning, as expressions are statements and they can be used inside a ternary.

Comment: @StefanPochmann:  Expressions are statements - but not all statements are expressions (break being an example), and the ternary operator requires expressions (not statements).

Comment: @MartinBonner I know. Not sure why you're telling me that.

Comment: I am trying to explain why break cannot be used inside a ternary.  Aah!  I think I see what you are trying to say:  it's not that break is a statement which is the problem, it's that it is *not* an expression.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

*(see my conversation with [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann) in the comments)*

Ternary operator is not for *only* statement, but rather for assignment or for expression (and `break` is an *only* statement):

```
a = 5 if cond else 3 #OK
do() if cond else dont() #also OK
do() if cond else break #not OK
```

use normal `if-else` statement to do statements:

```
if cond:
    do()
else:
    break
```

Comment: This is fine, but when I have to type it 5-6 times it looks ugly, is there a workaround?

Comment: Your examples aren't quite the same, as they *are* valid syntax

Comment: @TheChetan: no, there isn't. Python focuses on readability, not conciseness.

Comment: @TheChetan hmm... depends on the case, you could in fact make for loop and store the functions in `list` first for instance

Comment: @Ian, why does `dummy.remove(j) if j in dummy else exit` works?

Comment: I wouldn't hide the `break` argument in parentheses, as that's the main point. The ternary *can* be used for statements, e.g., `1 if 2 else 3` works fine as statement.

Comment: @sparkandshine you mean your answer? why it does not have syntax error? Hmm... I can help you check if you want, give me a minute

Comment: @StefanPochmann you are actually right, I think my terminology is inaccurate. But continue or break definitely not working... are they not statement?

Comment: @Ian `continue` and `break` are statements. Not sure why you're asking that, though.

Comment: @sparkandshine ah I get it... that is because `exit` is a function. If you use tool like `PyCharm` you can see that.. it is like function returning nothing

Comment: @StefanPochmann I mean, if they are statements and they (`break` and `continue`) cannot be used in the ternary, but other statement can (like your example), it means to say that statement cannot be put in the ternary is inaccurate. I was asking if my terminology in my answer is inaccurate

Comment: @Ian Ah, ok. The problem is that they're *only* statements, not expressions, and you [need an expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ah I get it, the correct phrase should be "not for *only* statement, it is for assignment and *expression*" :)

Comment: @Ian No, when you say it's "for assignment", that sounds like you're thinking of it as `(a = 5) if cond else 3` rather than `a = (5 if cond else 3)`. Doesn't really have anything to do with assignments. The issue simply is that the ternary needs an expression there and that `break` is no expression.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ah, no. I didn't mean that. The `a=5` is an expression *with* assignment I would say. But yes, the keyword here is *expression* - I mis-term it as *condition* initially. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Ian, I post my confusion as a question, ['exit' is not a keyword in Python, but no error occurs while using it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215406/exit-is-not-a-keyword-in-python-but-no-error-occurs-while-using-it), waiting for your answer:-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use break in Your loop logic can be re written using *itertools.takewhile* if you want a more succinct solution

```
digits = list(str(102))
dummy = list(str(102/2))

from itertools import takewhile

for d in takewhile(dummy.__contains__, digits):
    dummy.remove(d)
```

You can also remove the need for the else using a for loop by reversing your logic, check if j is not in dummy breaking when that is True:

```
for j in digits:
    if j not in dummy:
        break
    dummy.remove(j)
```

Also if you want to remove all occurrences of any of the initial elements from digits that are in dummy, remove won't do that for any repeating elements but using a list comp after creating a set of elements to remove will:

```
digits = str(102)
dummy = list(str(102/2))
st = set(takewhile(dummy.__contains__, digits))
dummy[:] = [d for d in dummy if d not in st]

print(dummy)
```

You can also iterate over a string so no need to call list on digits unless you plan on doing some list operations with it after.

Comment: Ugh, it's awkward to avoid the dunder method here; you can use `functools.partial` and `operator.contains`, e.g. `in_dummy = partial(contains, dummy)`. This seems like a lot of work to avoid the underscore method though, and no real benefits. A lambda could be used alternatively, e.g. `lambda e: e in dummy`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, yep,  I don't mind using `__contains__` in a case like this, definitely better than a lambda, might be interesting to time the comparisons.