# 'exit' is not a keyword in Python, but no error occurs while using it

Tags: python, exit, ternary-operator

I learn that `exit` is not a keyword in Python by,

```
import keyword
print('exit' in keyword.kwlist)     # Output: False
```

But there is no reminder of `NameError: name 'exit' is not defined` while using it. The output of the following snippet code makes me confused. Can anyone help me out?

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    cur=i if i<2 else exit

print(cur)
# Output
0
1
2
3
4
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

I am unable to get related info about `exit` from Python documentations, except for [`exit([code=None])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit).

Comment: @Ian, it seems that `exit` equals `Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit`, like a constant string.

Comment: Which is an interesting behavior, I suppose... like when you use console.. :)

Comment: You found https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/constants.html which says `exit` is a constant added by `site.py`, not a keyword or built-in function.  Not a duplicate, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keywords are part of the python syntax.  They usually have special meaning in statements (e.g. `for`, `del`, `if` ...).  This has other consequences -- e.g. you *can't* make a variable with the same name as a keyword.

*builtins* are [callable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) (e.g. functions or at least function-like) that python provides in the namespace by default.  examples of builtin functions are things like `sorted`, `id`, `vars`, ...

It's worth noting that `exit` is a convenience provided when in an interactive session.  It's highly encouraged to use [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) instead.

Comment: The python doc. calls `exit` a constant:  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/constants.html

Comment: @cdarke -- Yeah.  I'm guessing that's because they didn't have a better thing to call it.  It's not a builtin (don't want people using it in scripts because it isn't there ...).  With that said -- calling it a constant is a little weird in my opinion...

Comment: Agreed, python doesn't really have constants (OK, readonly properties), and it breaks PEP008 if it is one because it should be uppercase!

Answer (score 3):

`exit` is an instance of the `Quitter` class.  The `Quitter` class defines an `__repr__` method that returns the string that you see when you type `exit` into the shell.  It also defines a `__call__` method.  Just as `__init__` is called when you use a class like a function, `__call__` is called when an instance is used like a function.  Therefore, `exit()` calls the `__call__` method, which exits the program.

Answer (score 1):

[`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) is an [Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html) **added by the `site` module**.

> The [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) module (which is imported automatically during startup,
>   except if the [`-S`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id3) command-line option is given) adds several constants
>   to the built-in namespace. **They are useful for the interactive
>   interpreter shell and should not be used in programs**.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` is the `sys.exit` function when you are using the interactive console.

Many things exist while they are not keywords (e.g. `sum`, `int`...). So you can bind to existing names, but not to keywords

Comment: `exit` has the same functionality, but it is not the same as `sys.exit`.  See @zondo's post and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python